# Reinitialization problem of string in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am making a program and i have to initialize and reinitialize my NSString variable.I wrote  related code but when  am trying to reinitialize my NSString variable my program is being crashed. My macdelegate.h file are listed here.

```
@interface MacCalculatorAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

    UIWindow *window;

    UIButton *digitPressed;

    UIButton *operatorPressed;

    NSString *waitingOperation;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@property ( retain) NSString* waitingOperation;

-(IBAction) digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender;

-(IBAction) operatorPressed:(UIButton *)sender;

@end

And part of code of my macdelegate.m file are listed here.

- (id) init 

    {

    if (self = [super init])
        {

       self.waitingOperation=@"not set";//@"not set";           

        }

        return self;

    }


-(IBAction) digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

if(![@"not set" isEqualToString:waitingOperation])

    {
 waitingOperation=@"not set";//@"not set";

}
}

-(IBAction) operatorPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSString *operand=[[sender titleLabel] text];

    resultDisplay.text=operand;

    if([@"+" isEqualToString:operand])

    {    

 waitingOperation=@"+";//@"not set";        

    }

}

- (void)dealloc {

    [waitingOperation release];

    [window release];

    [super dealloc];

}
```

My all listed codes are above when i am running my program first time this is initialize well but when i am trying to reinitialize my program is doing nothing i suppose this is being crashed.
I am new with Objective-C help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you error do you get on screen ... Crash log ..

Comment: I am running in iPhone simulator how will i see my error log ? But i m seeing something is written like ..

GDB: Program received signal "SIGABRT".

Comment: you could see the crash log on your Console , i will come automatically when you run application in bebug ..

Comment: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.

Comment: Press `Cmd + 5` and select the first `Debug XXXXXXX`. Copy and paste the error log you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you have forgotten  **synthesize**  statement for your retaining variable **waitingOperation** and using it as `self.waitingOperation` would cause a crash, because run time system  could not find a setter function for the property **waitingOperation**

Add `@synthesize waitingOperation;` in your **implementation** file.

Use the modified code let me know if you still get the crash.

```
-(IBAction) digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
 {
    if(![ self.waitingOperation isEqualToString:@"not set"])
    {
     self.waitingOperation=@"not set";//@"not set";
   }
}

-(IBAction) operatorPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSString *operand=[[sender titleLabel] text];

    resultDisplay.text=operand;

    if([operand isEqualToString:@"+"])
    {    

      self.waitingOperation=@"+";//@"not set";        
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry to not mention i was declared it in my interface

Comment: @synthesize window,waitingOperation;
I was declared in implementation. Sorry to not mention.

Comment: hi thanks for reply but still getting crash. Here are the console ouput.

Comment: 2011-05-30 14:05:06.632 MacCalculator[1160:207] -[MacCalculatorAppDelegate operandPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6837350
2011-05-30 14:05:06.634 MacCalculator[1160:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MacCalculatorAppDelegate operandPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6837350'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Comment: @operandPressed : Show me where are you creating the UIButton which has operandPressed: has a actions.

Comment: I was previous defined a function with operandPressed and laterly i was changed it with operatorPressed. But still it is saying operandPressed. Thanks you got. please never mind new in iphone. I was creating UIButtons from MainWindow.Xib.

Comment: I am redesigning my application again connecting  with my  operatorPressed function and this is working fine now.It was my mistake to go on string initialization. Thanks @Jhalia this mistake is grabbed by you.